# how to call foo only if click OR focus fired

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive in which I bind `focus` and `click` events to element:

```
app.directive('mydirective', function () {
  return {
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $element.bind('click focus', function (e) {
        foo(e);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

I want to call `foo` once if `focus` or `click` event fired. But when clicking on element, `focus` event gets fired and `foo` gets called twice. how to prevent calling `foo` for the second time?

Edit:
Yes. I wasn't a good idea to mix hover with click and focus. Thanks every body

Comment: why don't you only use focus

Comment: @naeem-shaikh this is a kind of tooltip, so element may not be an input. I corrected my question

Comment: if you are going to bind click along with focus, then your foo function is fired twice, because for clicking on element you need to move your cursor focus to that element, so first focus will fire and then your are clicking that element so again foo is fire with click event, so please choose either click or focus event to bind with.

Comment: You can use .one from jquery or listen to Naeem Shaich because hover is always triggered. You can't ckick without hover

Comment: Note that you should **never** bind the `hover` event.

Comment: And why do you mix in `hover` at all, the mouse entering and leaving the element generally doesn't happen the same time you click? Are you just looking for `one()`, as noted above ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can debounce the events, that would only fire the function for the first event

```
$element.bind('click focus', function(e) {
    if ( !$(this).data('fired') ) foo(e);

    $(this).data('fired', true);

    setTimeout(function(self) {
        $(self).data('fired', false);
    }, 200, this);

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rzt01t16/1/)

Answer (score 2):

One more version of debounce function implementation:

```
link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {

    var callOnce = (function() {
        var timeout;
        return function(e, callback) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                callback.call(self, e);
            }.bind(this), 200); 
        };
    })();

    $element.bind('click focus mouseover', function(e) {
        callOnce.call(this, e, foo);
    });
}
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/HjwedaqUcGj6KncpDtwJ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

1. I would suggest using only the focus event if you want the `foo()` to be called on click and focus both because click will not fire alone but will also cause element to be focused,
2. as you mentioned that element may not be input, so you can use the click event only instead of focus
3. but in your case as you say it is fired 3 times, maybe click is fired twice and focus fired once OR focus fired twice and click fired once, in this case use `e.preventDefault();` in your click and focus event,

   ```
   app.directive('mydirective', function () {
     return {
       link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
         $element.bind('click', function (e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           foo(e);
         });
       }
     };
   });
   ```

   this way you can make sure same event callback doesn't continue executing twice.
4. Or the simplest way would be to check if the element is input the bind the focus event otherwise bind the click event

   ```
   app.directive('mydirective', function () {
     return {
       link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

           if(element is input)
           {    
                 $element.bind('focus', function (e) {
                   e.preventDefault();
                   foo(e);
                 });
           }
           else
           {       
                 $element.bind('click', function (e) {
                   e.preventDefault();
                   foo(e);
                 });
           }
       }
     };
   });
   ```